# Quotient space proof

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let Y be a supspace of a vector space $X$. Let $x=a+Y=b+Y$ and $y=c+Y=d+Y$. How can I show that $a+c+Y=a+d+Y=b+c+Y=b+d+Y$. I have tried somethings but I couldn't. How should I approach to this proof. Thank you..

Comment: What have you tried so far? You tagged proof-verification but showed no proof whatsoever.

Comment: What do you mean by $x=a+Y$? $Y$ is a vector space, $a$ is ... an element of $X$? and then $x=\{\,a+y:y{\rm\ in\ }Y\,\}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$u + Y = v + Y$ if and only if $u - v \in Y$. So $a - b = y_1$ and $c - d = y_2$, where $y_1, y_2 \in Y$. Note also that for all $y \in Y,\ y + Y = Y$.

So, $$(a + c) + Y = (a + d + y_2) + Y = (a + d) + (y_2 + Y) = (a + d) + Y$$

The other equalities follow similarly.